# awesome-typescript-loader throws on either OSX or Ubuntu, with different versions

Tags: macos, typescript, ubuntu, webpack, build

I have two strange errors; two different versions of awesome-typescript-loader throws errors on one OS(Ubuntu) and not on another(OSX), and vica verca - if I upgrade.

Case 1:

`"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.0",`

On OSX, it will throw this error:

`[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
[at-loader]: Child process failed to process the request:  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Then we think: OK, let's upgrade to:

`"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",`

And it works on OSX! Except, we build on Jenkins(Ubuntu)... And while Jenkins is happy about the 3.1.0 version and build with no issues, upgrading to 3.1.3 throws the following:

`[at-loader] Checking finished with 2 errors
Error in bail mode: [at-loader] ./src/pages/somePage.tsx:4:23
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'History'.`

.. This is related to React and React-router, I think? But why this module specifically?

In other words, we're in a position where we either cannot build without errors locally, or cannot build on a build server without errors.

What could be the issue? Is it with React-router-dom?

Here's a package.json sample:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "16.0.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "5.0.10",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.8",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.8",
    "@types/react-tap-event-plugin": "0.0.30",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.8",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.0", // Or 3.1.3 as mentioned
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-env": "5.0.5",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.4",
    "https": "1.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "redux-devtools": "3.4.0",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "tslint-react": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
  }
```

Comment: Hard to tell what the first error refers to without more context. But after upgrading, it seems that you import `History`, but the module is `history` (`"history": "4.7.2",`). Ubuntu's file system is case-sensitive, so the module isn't found, whereas macOS *can* be case-*in*sensitive. Not sure why it would have worked before upgrading though.

Comment: @MichaelJungo that was EXACTLY it! I suspect it's from the `fsevents` module which differs from macos to linux(Ubuntu throws an NPM WARN about it). Thank you!